# Dynamic input calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a calculator with 6 inputs that would automatically adjust input value based on the other input values.

I know I can manually listen for each input event and do individual calculation.

But I'm trying to implement a better method with shorter code.

You can see I have it partially working, but its a bit of a mess, when some inputs are changed. Its behaving weirdly

Appreciate any help

```js
;(function ($) {
    $('body').on('input', '.input-number', function () {
        const id = $(this).attr('id')
        const inputs = ['up', 'tu', 'pv', 'ip', 'cup', 'cv']
        const up = $('#up').val(),
            tu = $('#tu').val(),
            pv = $('#pv').val(),
            ip = $('#ip').val(),
            cup = $('#cup').val(),
            cv = $('#cv').val()
        const nv = {
            up: pv / tu,
            tu: pv / up,
            pv: tu * up,
            ip: ((cv - pv) / pv) * 100,
            cup: cv / tu,
            cv: (ip / 100) * up
        }
        inputs.forEach(c => {
            if (c !== id && nv[c] && nv[c] > 0) {
                $(`#${c}`).val(nv[c])
            }
        })
    })

    $('body').on('click', '.clear', function () {
        const inputs = ['up', 'tu', 'pv', 'ip', 'cup', 'cv']
        inputs.forEach(c => {
            $(`#${c}`).val('')
        })
    })
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-signin" style="max-width: 600px;margin: 0 auto">
    <h2>Purchased <button class="float-right button btn btn-secondary clear" type="button">Clear</button></h2>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="up">Unit Price</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" id="up" class="" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="tu">Total Unit(s)</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" id="tu" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="pv">Purchased Value</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" id="pv" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Current</h2>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="ip">Increase %</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" id="ip" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="cup">Unit Price</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" id="cup" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="cv">Current Value</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" id="cv" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the errors are coming from cyclic values..if you modify *pv*, you modify too *tu* and *up* and *up* is linked to *tu*....

Comment: yeah, I understand that and I wonder if there's a better way of implementing it without needing to create an input listener for each field

Comment: Shouldn't Unit price and Total units only accept user input and then be used to calculate Purchase value? Seems to me you have too many calculations going on

Comment: @charlietfl, its a mess. Im trying to enhance it so when any field is updated by a user, only one field from its formula is updated,

Comment: @charlietfl I want to have the freedom to update any field, and if its formula uses the value of other field, then only one of those field should be updated as well

Comment: something like this https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/percentage-increase